# How could I retain special character without replacing it with underscore?

Tags: filenames, quoting, sftp

I'm working on a file transfer script where I encounter a problem, when the file name look like `Dr' A`. The transfer script will fail due to following error:

```
sftp> put /path/Dr'\ A.tif
Unterminated quoted argument^
```

Is there a solution that could retain the single quote, without replacing it with underscore, while allowing me to handle other special characters as well.

Comment: Did you write this line in a script? If so, post the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the single quote within double quotes, as follows:

```
sftp> put /path/Dr"'"\ A.tif
```

It would also handle most other special characters as well.

If you want to have a single double-quote, then quote the single double-quote within double single-quotes :-) :

```
sftp> put /path/Dr'"'\ A.tif
```

Alternatively, you can escape the single or double quotes:

```
sftp> put /path/Dr\'\ A.tif
```